# VBA: filling of an array with a record set not working properly

Tags: arrays, vba, recordset

I try to fill an dynamic sized array with the fields of a DAO recordset:

```
Set daoRst3 = gDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM XYZ")
i = 0
daoRst3.MoveFirst
Do Until daoRst3.EOF
    ReDim Preserve recordSet(0 To i)
    recordSet(i) = daoRst3.Fields(0)
    daoRst3.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
```

The recordSet daoRst3 then has 148 fields (which reflects the correct amount from the query):

[image: Capture1]

But after looping the Do Until loop, the unsized array

```
Dim recordSet()
```

has only two fields, which is incorrect:

[image]

What is the problem here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `recordSet(i) = daoRst3.Fields(0).Value` ?

Comment: You are confusing the number of `Rows` and the number of `Fields`.

Comment: I've added Value, but that did not help.
@A.S.H : might be! Maybe I am accessing the DAO record set wrong?

The record set is one row with 147 columns.

Comment: Then dont use `daoRst3.MoveNext`, and iterate on the fields instead. `For i = 1 to rs.Fields.Count recordSet(i) = daoRst3.Fields(i).Value Next`

Comment: This causes a 'Subscript out of range' at line
recordSet(i) = daoRst3.Fields(i).Value

Comment: Ok the fields collection is zero-based. Change to `For i = 0 to rs.Fields.Count -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code compiled and worked:

```
Set daoRst3 = gDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM XYZ")
For i = 0 To daoRst3.Fields.Count - 1
ReDim Preserve recordSet(0 To i)
recordSet(i) = daoRst3.Fields(i).Value
Next
```

Thanks to user A.S.H.